# Using Macaulay2 to Write the Canonical Module as a Quotient of a Free Module

Tags: homological-algebra, macaulay2

Let $S$ be a polynomial ring over a field. Let $I$ be a homogeneous parameter ideal of $S.$ Observe that $S/I$ is an Artinian local ring, so it is Cohen-Macaulay, and it is finitely generated as an $S$-module. Even more, the projection of $S$ onto $S/I$ maps the homogeneous maximal ideal of $S$ onto the maximal ideal of $S/I,$ hence there exists a canonical module of $S/I.$ Explicitly, it is $\operatorname{Ext}_S^{\dim S}(S/I, S).$ One can find this canonical module by writing a (finite) minimal free resolution of $S/I$ as an $S$-module; applying $\operatorname{Hom}_S(-, S)$; and taking cohomology.

Let $S = \Bbb Q[x_1, \dots, x_5]$ and $I = (x_1 x_3, x_1 x_4, x_2 x_4, x_2 x_5, x_3 x_5) + (x_i^2 \mid 1 \leq i \leq 5).$ (One might recognize this as the sum of the Stanley-Reisner ideal of the five-cycle and the ideal generated by the squares of all of the variables.) I am attempting to use Macaulay2 to express the canonical module of $S/I$ as a quotient of a free $S$-module. Unfortunately, when I use the command `Ext^5(S^1/I, S^1)` in Macaulay2, it produces the following output that I am unable to interpret.

`cokernel {-7} | x_5 x_4 x_2 0 x_3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 x_1 0 0 0 0 |`

`{-7} | 0 0 0 x_5 -x_4 x_3 x_2 0 0 x_1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 |`

`{-7} | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 x_5 x_3 -x_2 x_1 x_4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 |`

`{-7} | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 x_5 x_4 x_3 x_1 0 0 x_2 0 0 |`

`{-7} | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 x_5 x_4 -x_3 x_2 x_1 |`

If I am correct, `{-7}` refers to the degree of the generators as a graded homomorphism; however, I'm not sure how this matrix $A$ is acting. Considering that this is a $5 \times 20$ matrix with entries in $S,$ I believe that this is acting by left-multiplication on the column vectors of $S^{\oplus 20},$ but I am not sure what a vector there looks like.

I have searched extensively for an interpretation of this output in the Macaulay2 documentation, but I have not found anything to settle my question. Ultimately, if I can decipher the output $\operatorname{cokernel}(A),$ then I would like to use the fact that $\omega_{S/I} = \operatorname{Ext}_S^5(S/I, S) = S^{\oplus 5} / \operatorname{coker}(A)$ is the canonical module of $S/I$ to determine the [idealization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.08265.pdf) of $\omega_{S/I}$ over $S.$ I would appreciate any insight or suggestions.

Comment: Notice that the ideal $I$ is *not* a Stanley--Reisner ideal for the cycle (these are always square-free, you want the complementary set of generators, or just remove the squares). Also, $S$ is just a polynomial ring, so what do you mean by "I am not sure what a vector there looks like."?

Comment: You are correct. For one, I had not written down the correct ideal, but also, I failed to mention that I wanted to add the sum of all squares.

Comment: As for your other question, Macaulay2 has described the canonical module as the cokernel of some map induced by (left-)multiplication by some $5 \times 20$ matrix with entries in $S.$ In order to find this, I imagine I would first attempt to describe the image of $A.$

Comment: Either way, what I had would have produced the sum of the Stanley-Reisner ideal of the five-cycle (with a possibly non-standard labeling) and the ideal generated by the squares of the variables. I apologize for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this will clear your confusion, but let me just go through some of what you say in your post.

First, notice that if $\Delta$ is some abstract simplicial complex over a set $X$, then the Stanley--Reisner ideal $I_\Delta$ is generated by the *square-free* monomials $x_{i_1}\cdots x_{i_k}$ where $\{i_1,\ldots,i_k\}$ is *not* in $\Delta$. If you take the $5$-cycle to be $12,23,34,45,51$, then what you wrote is somewhat the opposite of this, though if you remove the squares you will get the SR-ideal for the cycle $13524$,

*For the resolutions*. You can ask M2 to tell you what the resolution of $I$ as an $S$ module looks like, and then ask for the transpose of the $5$th differential:

```
o53 = R

o53 : PolynomialRing

i54 : I = ideal(x1*x2,x2*x3,x3*x4,x4*x5,x5*x1,x1^2,x2^2,x3^2,x4^2,x5^2)

                                                  2    2    2    2    2
o54 = ideal (x1*x2, x2*x3, x3*x4, x4*x5, x1*x5, x1 , x2 , x3 , x4 , x5 )

o54 : Ideal of R

i55 : M = module R/I

o55 = cokernel | x1x2 x2x3 x3x4 x4x5 x1x5 x1^2 x2^2 x3^2 x4^2 x5^2 |

                             1
o55 : R-module, quotient of R

i56 : C = res M 

       1      10      25      31      20      5
o56 = R  <-- R   <-- R   <-- R   <-- R   <-- R  <-- 0
                                                     
      0      1       2       3       4       5      6

o56 : ChainComplex

i57 : (Hom(C,module R)).dd_(-4)

o57 = {-7} | x5    0   -x4 x3  0  -x2 x1 0  0   0   0   0  0  0  0  0   0  0   0  | 
      {-7} | 0  -x5 0   0   -x4 0  0   0  x3 0   -x2 x1  0  0  0  0  0   0  0   0  |  
      {-7} | 0  0   -x5 0   0   x4 0   0  0  -x3 0   -x2 x1 0  0  0  0   0  0   0  |  
      {-7} | 0  0   0   0   0   x5 0   0  0  0   0   0   0  x4 0  x3 -x2 x1 0   0  |   
      {-7} | 0  0   0   0   0   0  0   x5 0  0   0   0   0  0  x4 0  x3  0  -x2 x1 |
      --------------------------------------------------------------------------
              5       20
o57 : Matrix R  <--- R
```

Thus, you can see that the matrix that computes $\mathrm{Ext}^5_S(S/I,S)$ is the above, I assume the one that M2 gave you is obtained from this one by some elementary operations.
At any rate, you compute this module as the quotient of $S^5$ by the image of this matrix.

Comment: I apologize for the initial confusion. Thank you for your helpful response. Call your matrix $A.$ I understand that Ext will be the quotient of $S^{\oplus 5}$ by the image of this matrix, but I'm still a little uncertain as to what is being multiplied by this matrix to produce the image.

Comment: By the way, am I correct to assume that the copies of `{-7}` appearing to the left of each row of the matrix is the degree of the map? If so, then it should be important to keep track of this in order to determine the idealization because it is a graded module.